# How to get the power of a big number raised with another big number in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy to find the powers of individual elements from an array/matrix that contains large numbers. I am not getting the desired output, which I can get by using calculator.

```py
m = np.mod(np.power(96, 17), 703)
print(m)
```

The code prints 0, but the expected output is 153.

Answer (score 1):

The largest numpy integer is not large enough:

```
np.int64(96 ** 17)
# => OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Using numpy integers in `np.power` silently swallows the error, and returns `0`, which is the source of your problem:

```
np.power(96, 17, dtype=np.int64)
# => 0
```

The largest numpy float will work, but you have to specify it explicitly; also, you need to keep in mind there might be errors due to loss of precision, in some cases:

```
np.power(96, 17, dtype=np.float128)
# => 4.9958680767981378818e+33
np.mod(np.power(96, 17, dtype=np.float128), 703)
# => 153.0
```

But it would still be the best to use native arbitrary size integers, as you are guaranteed a correct result:

```
96 ** 17 % 703
# => 153
```

However, this loses us the ability to do the calculation with numpy array operands. One would think that we could do this by specifying `dtype=int`, but `int` will be interpreted as `np.int_`; so this won't do either:

```
np.power(96, 17, dtype=int)
# => 0
```

However, specifying `dtype=object` **does** seem to do the trick, making sure numpy treats it as a Python object (while still being able to take advantage of vectorisation semantics of numpy):

```
np.mod(np.power(96, 17, dtype=object), 703)
# => 153
```

Comment: math on object dtype arrays is hit or miss.  It operates at list comprehension speeds, and converts the math into operators  or 'methods'.  `np.sin` fails because few classes implement 'sin' as a method.

Comment: Good thing you wrote `vectorization  *semantics*, not *speed*

Comment: @hpaulj Indeed, intentionally so.

Comment: Thank you so much for your invaluable help! Your guidance and support made a significant difference, and I'm truly grateful for your time and effort. Your expertise and willingness to assist have been instrumental in resolving my concerns. Once again, thank you for your kindness and assistance.